# How to deepcopy a function in python

Tags: python, function, deep-copy

I need to compute a function in a number of cases, and then to sum over all these cases. I figured one way to do that would be to create either a list, a dictionary or an array of functions, but no matter what I do the previous function is erased in the loop.

```
def general_func(r, arg1, arg2):
    return r*arg1*arg2

fun_list = []
for i in range(N):
    arg1_i, arg2_i = my_arr[1:3]
    def local_func(r):
        return general_func(r, arg1_i, arg2_i)
    fun_list.append(local_func)
```

I have tried a number of things, but no matter what I do, I always end up with a tuple of N times the same function.

I am also unsure on how I would sum over all functions in the end to keep one big function which would be the sum of all others.

Comment: It's not the function that's being erased, it's the local variables changing.  Do `def local_func(r, arg1_i=arg1_i, arg2_i=arg2_i):` so you capture the current values at the time you define the function.

Comment: what are N and my_arr? You might want lambda. Also local_func is always the same, so you should expect it to be the same. You never used i

Answer (score 0):

Following Samwell's answer, I defined functions in the loop:

```
def local_func(r, arg1_i=arg1_i, arg2_i=arg2_i):
```

And was able to properly define my array of functions.